# Android Admob sample error :(

Tags: android, admob

This project was coped almost exacatly from the example on the admob page but it still does not work!
Here is my class file:

```
 package com.firecow.admobtest;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * A simple {@link Activity} that embeds an AdView.
 */
public class AdMobTesterActivity extends Activity {
    /** The view to show the ad. */
    private AdView adView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14fd022edb48e8");

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

... and my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I dont know what to do, I only get this error in the logcat

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdView
```

What does this mean? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the AdMob SDK in your project. If you're using Eclipse, [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals) will show you how to do that.

If you don't yet have the SDK downloaded, you can do that from your AdMob control panel, or from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download).

Lastly, check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. It should have, added to it, the lines of code bolded in that same tutorial. *(Side note: you showed us your layout file, not your manifest.)*

Also make sure you have cleaned and rebuilt your project after doing this.

Comment: I followed the turorial completely in a new project and the same thing happened...

Comment: If that's the case, I believe it's a libs error. In the tutorial, it shows you how to add the library, but I believe in your case it's not getting exported. If you need to know how to add it to the Order/Export list, check **[here](http://android.okhelp.cz/noclassdeffounderror-com-google-ads-adview-adt-17/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have copied admob.jar in to the libs folder and don't forget to add admob activity tag in Menifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
</activity>
```